# Is there a way to explicitly define a policy for a Nova resource in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

The scenario is I want to be able to manage staff user types independently of other users. Only staff should be able to see and interact with the staff resource and no other user type should have access to it.

So I have `App\Nova\User` and `App\Nova\Staff` resources, and both of these have their `$model` property pointing to the `App\Models\User` model. This works great and does everything I need it to do.

The problem I have now is with permissions. I also make use of Laravel's policies in places and would like to do the same here, but I don't know how to make a policy specifically for the Staff resource because it references the User model?
I basically don't want non-staff users being able to view any, or perform any CRUD operation on Staff. I believe I can hide staff from the side bar but my understanding is a user can still access it with the URL.

I know I could create a Staff model that extends the User model and then my Nova resource can point to that new Staff model, but I had issues with that as that's how I had it set up originally, prior to using `spatie/laravel-permissions` for user roles/permissions.

I have a few other user types I'd like to create resources for as well so they can be managed independently, even though they're all in the same users table. I will end up with something like staff being a kind of super admin, with another user type of customer admin who can see all the users within their customer, so they may see an 'Employee' resource, and like above, only customer admins should be able to see that, and certainly only see their own employees within it.

This is my first time using Nova so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As per nova documentation you can only apply the policies to a model and it works perfectly when each resource points to its own model.

But in your case, App\Nova\User and App\Nova\Staff resources, both of these have their $model property pointing to the App\Models\User model.

So, here is the solution, what you can do is create a separate model for App\Nova\Staff i.e App\Models\Staff and extends the App\Nova\User model.

```
class Staff extends User{ }
```

Now App\Nova\Staff resource should point to the App\Models\Stuff model.

At this point if you apply policy to App\Models\Staff , it will work.

Comment: It will work partially. It was what I've done before I came here. Then you need to specify that the `Staff` model using the `users` table, then relations won't load properly due to foreign keys not matching when guessed by Eloquent based on the model name - got to overwrite these too and who know what else.. it is messy!

Answer (score 0):

@Nathan you can authenticate different models with specific auth guards.

After that you can write different logic for users in your policy.

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can update the model.
 *
 * @param Model $user
 * @param \App\Document $document
 * @return mixed
 */
public function update(Model $user, Document $document)
{
    return $user instanceof User ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a private method to the Policy and accepting an Elequent model on the Policy methods:

```
public function viewAny(Model $user): bool
{
    if($this->isAdmin($user)) {
        return true;
    };
    return false;
}

private function isAdmin(Model $user)
{
    if($user instanceof AdminUser) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($user instanceof User) {
        return false;
    }
    throw new \Exception('User type not supported');
}
```